# Installing Apache Spark 3.5.0 on macOS

Tags: macos, apache-spark, pyspark, installation, terminal

I am trying to get pyspark to work on my device to start a course and I am new to macOS. I followed the steps in this article [here](https://medium.com/luckspark/installing-spark-2-3-0-on-macos-high-sierra-276a127b8b85) but I used different version of Spark and python while the rest is the same. When I reach the last step and type pyspark in the terminal I get this message "zsh: command not found: pyspark"

```
This is what I changed my .bash_profile to:

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.jdk/Contents/Home/
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/sarah/server/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3
export SBT_HOME=/Users/sarah/server/sbt
export SCALA_HOME=/Users/sarah/server/scala-2.11.12
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SBT_HOME/bin:$SBT_HOME/lib:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME/lib:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$PATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3


PATH=”/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:${PATH}”
export PATH
```

And this is what I have when I run /usr/libexec/java_home -V:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    21.0.1 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 21.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.391.13 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_391 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home
```

[And these are the programs I downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83AND.png)

My device:
Model Name:MacBook Pro - Model Identifier:Mac14,10 - Chip:Apple M2 Pro

I tried to quit the terminal and open it again but this didn't work out. I am new to terminals too. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this link: https://medium.com/free-code-camp/installing-scala-and-apache-spark-on-mac-os-837ae57d283f

I hope this helps to fix the issue!

Comment: Did you make sure to run `source .bash_profile`? I was trying to recreate your issue. Please open a new instance of the terminal and try again.

Comment: That solved it, thanks a lot vnk!

Comment: I recommend you to install spark on a docker container. It'll be easier to maintain and work with.